# MVC @Url.Content vs @Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have looked online but was unable to find the difference between
using  `@Url.Content` vs `@Url.Action`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`Url.Content` is used when you wish to resolve a URL for any file or resource on your site and you would pass it the relative path:

```
@Url.Content("~/path/file.htm")
```

`Url.Action` is used to resolve an action from a controller such as:

```
@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { variable = value })
```

See here for more info:

<strike>http://geekswithblogs.net/liammclennan/archive/2008/05/21/122298.aspx</strike> - Dead link

Answer (score 10):

[`@Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) is used to create a URL to an Action in a controller. For example, assuming you had a controller that looked like this:

```
public YourControllerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult YourAction() { /* stuff */ }
}
```

You could create a URL that invokes the action with it like this:

```
Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")
```

[`@Url.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) resolves a virtual path into an absolute path. Example:

```
Url.Content("~/images/image.jpg")
```

Comment: Does this mean Url.Action will not always resolve to an absolute path?