# Session data is null while Using FileResult to return an image using mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a Controller with an Action inside that returns an image using using FileResult.

```
public ActionResult GetScreeny(long id)
        {

            if (Session["userID"] == null) 
            {
                return Json("no session/cookie");
            }

            long userID = 
                Convert.ToInt64(
                    Session["userID"].ToString()
                );



            var dir = Library.AppVars.FILESERVER_IO_IMG_SAVE_PATH + userID.ToString();

            var path = Path.Combine(dir, id + ".jpg");
            return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

This is how I request the image from a View:

```
<img id="imgtoshow" src="@Url.Content(Library.AppVars.siteURL + "/Files/GetScreeny/" + ViewBag.screenID)" alt="IMAGE" width="100%" />
```

Works on Desktop, but not on Mobile :[
How does  sessions/cookies works on mobile?

Comment: Session is in strict bond with an `SessionId`, this was present in Cookies/Url?

Comment: @adricadar thanks for your comment. I tried using Cookies instead of session, but the cookie was always NULL, even though I could access cookies directly. The question would be, when a browser requests an image to an URL using the "<img  />" tag, does it sends the browser cookies or is it some other kind of request?

Comment: In mobili phone it's possible to get `Session` **null** because `SessionId` it's not stored in `Cookies`. This is why on desktop browser *everything works fine*.

Comment: To answer to your question, a `<img />` don't send the image in `Cookies`, it's send the image in *someplace* to be processed (displayed).

Comment: @adricadar thank you so much for your explanation, is there an alternative so provide images if the mobile user is logged in ?

Comment: You can see on mobile if user is logged in? Can you provide some small parts of code related to problem?

Comment: @adricadar I have edited my question to add the code; if the user is not logged in, he receives a text instead of the image. Works well on Desktop, but not on mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `src` might be wrong. Because you don't return *a path to server* you are returning *an image* with *bytes and all the stuffs*. That's [why `Url.Action`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186163/mvc-url-content-vs-url-action) look better.

```
<img id="imgtoshow" src="@Url.Action("GetScreeny", "Files", new { id = ViewBag.screenID })" alt="IMAGE" width="100%" />
```

---

Thare are many reasons [why session *work*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work) in desktop browser and *in mobile browsers* (your case) or other browsers **don't**.

The most abvious reason is that, `SessionId` is not set in cookies. Like the image below (this is how an `SessionId` looks in ASP.NET).

[image: SessionId]

You can enter *Developer Tools* in any browser to see the `Cookies` (this example is from *Chrome*).

Notes:

1)  Session is *per user*, this means if you **set session in *browser1*** and try to access it in *browser2*, won't work.

2) Session is stored *on server side* that's why needs an `SessionId` to get stored data for specific user (by `SessionId`).

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation. Is there an alternative so provide images if the mobile user is logged in without using cookies or sessions?

Comment: From a mobile: each image request is a new session apart form the page the IMG actually resides in?

Comment: @Rockster This is not valid for mobile or desktop. I'm guessing that mobile phone browser isn't allowed to store cookies.

Comment: thanks again for your comment. But the session works if I check it directly from a Controller, but calling by requesting an <img /> seems to not be working, I have edited my question, please check the code