# Kendo autocomplete template img src from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, autocomplete, kendo-template

There are many examples how to set icon from static content. For example:

```
Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("employess")
    .Placeholder("Find Product..")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .HighlightFirst(true)
    .Template("<span><img src='/Content/Images/default-photo.jpg' " +
    "width='20' height='20' />&nbsp;${data.Name}</span>")
...
```

Is it possible to set image src from database by ${data.ImageId}?
I tried to make controller method and paste `Url.Action` instead of `default-photo` but compiler doesn't understand what do I want to do.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: It should work. Your action should be something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1349318/1267304) and `<img src='" + Url.Action("Image/1") + "' />`  should work as well.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I can not pass the Image Id value: `Url.Action("GetImage", "Search", new {imageId = data.ImageId})`

Comment: That part is easy, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the image name in your `data` object and the image is in your Content folder, you can use [`Url.Content()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) to get the path to it, as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8186202/1267304). So your template could be like:

```
.Template("<span><img src='" + Url.Content("~/Images/") + "${data.ImageName}' " +
"width='20' height='20' />&nbsp;${data.Name}</span>")
```

The url will result in something like: `Content/Images/image.jpg`.

But if you have only the id and need to *generate*  the image as a http response, you can create an action method for that, as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349318/1267304). So your template would be:

```
.Template("<span><img src='" + Url.Action("GetImage", "Search") + "/${data.ImageId}' " +
"width='20' height='20' />&nbsp;${data.Name}</span>")
```

The url will result in something like: `Search/GetImage/1`.

In both cases you somehow *concat* the Javascript variable in an ASP.Net string, as showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112223/1267304) of a friend of mine.