# how to call controllers function with ajax when click button MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im new in MVC,I have problem the button cannot call Ajax function to render Action in controller.

this bellow my script button

```
<input type="submit" value="show" class="btn btn-success" name="submitButton" onclick="OnActionClick()" />
```

My Ajax

```
function OnActionClick() {
    alert("Error when update data");   
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Report/ViewReport")",
            data: {
                name:'try'
            },
            success: function () {
               alert("ok"); 
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error when update data");                    
            }
        });        
}
```

and here my Action in controller

```
public ActionResult ViewReport(string name)
    {
        Database db = new Database("Collections");
        List<report> data = new List<report>();
        data = db.Fetch<report>(@"select top 10 * from SampleTbl where name = @0",new object[]{name});
        return View(data);
    }
```

Comment: Try Changing url to `url: "Report/ViewReport"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Url.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) instead of using `Url.Content()`.

> Generates a fully qualified URL to an action method.

```
url: '@Url.Action("ViewReport", "Report")',
```

And you should `type="button"`

```
<input type="button" onclick="OnActionClick()" />
```

Comment: yes,, I success use that method,, but I want to use ajax, how to make it?

Comment: @IndraSuandi, You should use `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use @Url.Action() and not @Url.Content().
Please see this for difference between the two:
[MVC @Url.Content vs @Url.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186163/mvc-url-content-vs-url-action)