# How to use properly razor syntax inside script block?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I work on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

I try to use razor syntax in script area on the cshtml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/Account/Login/")';

    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
     {
          url = '@Url.Content("~/Account/GetLayers/")';
     }
</script>
```

But when I run the page I get on this row:

```
url = '@Url.Content("~/Account/GetLayers/")';
```

This error:

> CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

So I tried this:

```
 url = "@Url.Content("~/Account/GetLayers/")";
```

But now I get this error:

> CS1002: ; expected

Any idea why my attempts above don't work?

Comment: Mixing JS & Razor code is confusing and prone to XSS.  You should pass values from the server using `data-` attributes instead.

Comment: `var isRequested = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Request.IsAuthenticated) if(isRequested) { ....`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are already in a C# code block, (opened by your if condition statement). If you want to mix  js/plain text with C# code in razor, use `@:` prefix

If you are trying to generate the relative url to an action method, you should consider using `Url.Action` method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var url = '@Url.Action("Login","Account")';
  @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
  {
      @:url = '@Url.Action("GetLayers","Account")';
  }
</script>
```

The `@:` tells razor that the following expression should be considered as not code, but plain text

It is same as using the `<text>` tag

```
@if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <text>url = '@Url.Action("Index")'</text>;
}
```

You can convert this to a one liner with ternary operator

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@(Request.IsAuthenticated ? Url.Action("GetLayers","Account") 
                                                   :  Url.Action("Login","Account"))';
    console.log(url);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for post! can you please explain?What you mean ready in a code block?

Comment: Why?What is difference?

Comment: What is difference if I use Url.Action or @Url.Content?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186163/mvc-url-content-vs-url-action

Comment: You opened a c# code block by starting `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)`. If you want to mix plain text inside that, you ned to use `<text></text>`

Comment: Since the methods are the same, why not use the ternary operator inside the method?  `var url = @Url.Action(Request.IsAuthenticated ? "GetLayers" : "Login", Account")`.  Depending on where this code is being executed, it might be better in the controller anyway.

Comment: Yes. That will work too here as both of this actions are from same controller. All it needs is a string (for the action name).