# How to route folder in ASP.NET MVC with all relative paths?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

For example I have an angular project folder inside of my **ASP.NET MVC 4** project folder.

```
MyAspProjectFolder/App/AngularFolder/dist/index.html
```

When I redirect from action to this file, by using

```
return Redirect(Url.Content("App/angularproj/dist/index.html"));
```

in open the html file, but paths inside this html file understand wrong. For example, in this HTML file I have a link to script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js">
```

ASP trying to get it relative from localhost, for example

```
http://localhost:53131/polyfills.bundle.js
```

But It not places in localhost, it's under

```
App/angularproj/dist/polyfills.bundle.js
```

Is it possible to say ASP, that when I do some route ( for example *App/angularproj/* ) it means everything under this route also relative from this route.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186163/mvc-url-content-vs-url-action)

Try using `@Url.Content("~/path/file.htm")` Or

```
@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { variable = value })
```